# Emacs Lisp search-backward

Tags: search, emacs, lisp

**Preamble**

Using VTK library with C++, quite often I have to write something like this:

```
vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandZoom *isrbz = vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandZoom::New();
```

Furthermore, every time I need to use a new VTK class in my program, I have to go somewhere up the source file and add #include "vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandZoom.h"

How do I automate it, so I have to type each of the excruciatingly long class names one time instead of three?

I tried writing an Emacs minor mode for it. There are probably existing solutions out there already (YaSnippet?), but I thought that writing it myself would be a good excercise, too.

**Code**

```
;vtk-mode.el
;add to .emacs:
;(load  "vtk-mode")
;(global-set-key [(control =)] 'expand-vtk)

(defun expand-vtk ()
  (interactive)
  (setq now (point))
  (setq vtkstart (search-backward "vtk"))
  (setq vtkend (- (search-forward " ") 1))
  (setq vtkname (buffer-substring vtkstart vtkend))

  ;check for #include "vtkBlah.h"
  (setq includename (format "#include \"%s.h\"\n" vtkname))
  (search-backward includename nil (append-include-vtk includename))
  (goto-char (+ now (length includename)))

  (insert (format "= %s::New();" vtkname)))

(defun append-include-vtk (incname)
  (goto-char 0)
  (insert incname))
```

**Problem**

Basically, it works, except that searching for an include name always fails, e. g.:

```
vtkSomething *smth /*press C-= here, it looks backward for 
#include "vtkSomething.h", can't find it and 
calls append-include-vtk, adding it to the beginning 
of the file, then comes back here and expands this line into: */

vtkSomething *smth = vtkSomething::New();

//and let's add another instance of vtkSomething...
vtkSomething *smth2 /*press C-= again, it looks backward for 
#include "vtkSomething", and fails, despite the fact 
that it was added by the previous command. So it adds it again."*/
```

What am I doing wrong here with search-backward?

(there's another (at least one) bug in the code, I shouldn't add the (length includename) if the search-backward for it was successful, but for now I am more interested in how to make it successful, in the first place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it. Somehow I got an idea that the third argument of search-backward (noerror) is a callback, which it isn't. Therefore it is evaluated every time, not just when the search fails. It should be something like this instead:

```
(defun expand-vtk ()
  (interactive)
  (setq now (point))
  (setq vtkstart (search-backward "vtk"))
  (setq vtkend (- (search-forward " ") 1))
  (setq vtkname (buffer-substring vtkstart vtkend))

  ;check for #include "vtkBlah.h"
  (setq includename (format "#include \"%s.h\"\n" vtkname))
  (if (search-backward includename nil t) 
      (goto-char now) 
      (progn (append-include-vtk includename) 
             (goto-char (+ now (length includename)))))  

  (insert (format "= %s::New();" vtkname)))

(defun append-include-vtk (incname)
  (goto-char 0)
  (insert incname))
```

Answer (score 1):

A command that's built into Emacs and will help you avoid typing excruciatingly long class names is `dabbrev-expand` (bound to `M-/`):

```
(dabbrev-expand ARG)

Expand previous word "dynamically".

Expands to the most recent, preceding word for which this is a prefix.
If no suitable preceding word is found, words following point are
considered.  If still no suitable word is found, then look in the
buffers accepted by the function pointed out by variable
`dabbrev-friend-buffer-function'.
```

Having typed `vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandZoom` once, the next time you need it you just type `vtkI M-/`.

Comment: Thanks. I know that one and use it whenever possible. However, it's not always useful in this particular case, because the library has so many long class names sharing so many long common prefixes. There are, for example, about 12 classes starting with "vtkInteractorStyle...", and in case I need to use more than one on the same source, I still have to type "vtkInteractorStyleX..." and "vtkInteractorStyleY..."